# Look and tell me what you see! Is it correct as a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation

> Look and tell me what you see.

Is it correct as a statement, or should I add quotation marks?

Comment: Does your sentence contain a direct quote, a verbatim record of somebody's words?

Comment: You haven't given us enough context to know.

Comment: I am asking because i have  been told that this statement is incorrect  and i shoud say (look , and tell me what do you see ?

Comment: It does not need any further punctuation unless it is being presented as a quotation from someone.  There are a few people who might claim there should be a comma after "Look", but they would be wrong in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you mean that, because you're quoting an old forgotten song, you have to use quotation marks, then, by all means, use them.

That said, "tell me what you see" is a common enough expression.

The "look" part is a bit dubious, though. Here are some suggestions:

> Take a look at this picture and tell me what you see.
>
> Look at this and tell me what you see.
>
> Observe and tell me what you see.
>
> Look carefully at this picture and tell me what you see.

Comment: Thanks  Ricky i am a kindergarten  teacher and i always ask my students  to look at the picture  on the board  and to tell me what do they see so i thought  it's  good to ask if the statement  is correct

Comment: @user155776: Well, then, this merits an edit. Give me a minute.

Comment: "Look and see" is a common idiom.  "Look and tell me what you see" is just a minor variation on that, and perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

```
Look and tell me what you see.
```

This is perfectly correct as a statement, and you would only need to add quotation marks if this is dialogue or a direct quote from somewhere.

However, the statement

```
Look, and tell me what do you see?
```

is INCORRECT unless this is dialogue. To clarify, what you're doing here is combining a statement and a question without proper syntax. Even if this is dialogue, the better alternative would be

```
"Look, and tell me, what do you see?"
```

Comment: Many thanks fi12's i am a kindergarten  teacher and i always ask my students  to look at the picture  on the board  and to tell me what do they see so i thought  it's  good to ask if the statement  is correct thanks

Answer (score -1):

This sentence needs adjusted punctuation in order to deal with both of the commands and the question: Look and tell me, what do you see?